# How can I access public API Information without Login?

Tags: objective-c, oauth-2.0, eventbrite, yelp

I'm trying to access public information from API's without actually having users grant access to the API in my mobile Application. Is this actually possible, or are the Oauth permissions for any sort of access to an API?

**For example**, I want my application to be able to pull a list of nearby restaurants for my application without asking the user if Yelp can access the application. Since the user just wants nearby food information, the request for restaurants isn't user specific, and the user shouldn't actually have to login.

**Another example** is if I want Eventbrite to simply give me a list of upcoming events. Is there a way to get this list without having a user authenticate Eventbrite within my application itsself?

Comment: You could consider building an [API proxy](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/build-simple-api-proxy) that handles the auth on the back end and serves to your users without auth?

Answer (score 0):

You can call an API endpoint with your own token (between your Eventbrite account and your application key), and if the data is public (even if it's 'owned' by a different Eventbrite account) we'll return the data.

For example, if you want a list of events across our Event Directory (Event Search endpoint: http://developer.eventbrite.com/docs/event-search/) you can call this method with your own OAuth token (you can grab your OAuth token here: http://eventbrite.com/myaccount/apps).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! Don't know if this is too specific, but how do you call the endpoint? I'm still pretty new to iOS and am still trying to figure out how to use OAuth. If I make a request to the service, wouldn't I have to still confirm the use of Eventbrite in my Application or would a request for public information automatically return the desired information?